# Is there a way I could combine these two LINQ statements?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following:

```
var data = _cityRepository.GetAll(
    u => u.PartitionKey == pk & 
    u.RowKey.CompareTo(lowerBound) >= 0 & 
    u.RowKey.CompareTo(upperBound) < 0);

details =
    from d in data
    select new City.Grid
    {
        PartitionKey = d.PartitionKey,
        RowKey = d.RowKey,
        ShortTitle = d.ShortTitle,
        Created = d.Created,
        Modified = d.Modified,
        ModifiedBy = d.ModifiedBy
    };

detailsList = details
    .OrderBy(item => item.Modified)
    .Select((t, index) => new City.Grid()
    {
        PartitionKey = t.PartitionKey,
        RowKey = t.RowKey,
        Row = index + 1,
        ShortTitle = t.ShortTitle,
        Created = t.Created,
        Modified = t.Modified,
        ModifiedBy = t.ModifiedBy
    })
    .ToList();
```

The problem for me is that I am not sure how to combine the second as it uses this:

```
Select((t, index) => new City.Grid()
```

Is there a way I could combine these statements into one or if that's not possible could I just combine the last two?

Comment: There are three statements here, not two. And given their simple structure, you can join all three together with nothing fancier than a simple search and replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure - it's ugly, but this has all three:

```
var query = _cityRepository.GetAll(
                               u => u.PartitionKey == pk & 
                               u.RowKey.CompareTo(lowerBound) >= 0 & 
                               u.RowKey.CompareTo(upperBound) < 0)
                .Select(d => new City.Grid
                        {
                            PartitionKey = d.PartitionKey,
                            RowKey = d.RowKey,
                            ShortTitle = d.ShortTitle,
                            Created = d.Created,
                            Modified = d.Modified,
                            ModifiedBy = d.ModifiedBy                          
                        }
                .OrderBy(item => item.Modified)
                .Select((t, index) => new City.Grid()
                {
                    PartitionKey = t.PartitionKey,
                    RowKey = t.RowKey,
                    Row = index + 1,
                    ShortTitle = t.ShortTitle,
                    Created = t.Created,
                    Modified = t.Modified,
                    ModifiedBy = t.ModifiedBy
                })
                .ToList();
```

It would be more sensible to avoid creating new `City.Grid` objects twice:

```
var query = _cityRepository.GetAll(
                               u => u.PartitionKey == pk & 
                               u.RowKey.CompareTo(lowerBound) >= 0 & 
                               u.RowKey.CompareTo(upperBound) < 0)
                .OrderBy(item => item.Modified)
                .Select((t, index) => new City.Grid()
                {
                    PartitionKey = t.PartitionKey,
                    RowKey = t.RowKey,
                    Row = index + 1,
                    ShortTitle = t.ShortTitle,
                    Created = t.Created,
                    Modified = t.Modified,
                    ModifiedBy = t.ModifiedBy
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. The latter was what I was looking for but I wasn't sure how to put it all together. I will give it a try.

Comment: jon , in query syntax - , would  `into` could helped here ? ( i think it should be converted to query syntax...[all 3 queries ])

Comment: @Royi Namir: No. Query expressions don't have syntax for the overload of select which provides the index to the projection.

Comment: @JonSkeet so youre saying that the third query is a problematic since of its index projection ? ( which doesnt have equalization in query syntx )?